# PHP Server not returning data in another country

Tags: php, mysql, firemonkey

I made mobile app with delph firemonkey, and my own lamp server, MySQL has two tables and everything works perfect locally (data from BOTH tables) - in local network or from outside, BUT I get very strange problem, when friend is trying to use app from another country, it reads first table fine, but when need to get data from other table - receives nothing?

I tried to debug but simply when he is trying to access from another country, PHP returns NOTHING? How is this possible? Is his ISP filtering something? (if yes, how I can read data from table1 in app)?

Comment: An ISP would not know about your DB tables. Have you checked your error logs? What interaction is occurring with the other table?

Comment: app just sends command to php server (all parameters OK, and as I said, it works in our country perfectly) - but in friends country, first table (category list is read ok) and THEN we needs to read data from that table, mobile app does not receive anything (in his country)

Comment: Does the request make it to your server? Have you looked at your access logs?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your method of debugging?

Answer (score 2):

believe it or not, the answer was pretty simple, it crashed php script, because query had different decimal separator than expected, so when i defined `.` as decimal separator in firemonkey app, all is good!